# fork is confusing me

Tags: c, fork

Can anyone, please, explain how does this code work ?

```
int main()
{
  printf("Hello");
  fork();
  printf("World");
}
```

Prints:

```
HelloWorldHelloWorld
```

My exact question is, why `hello` is printed twice. Isn't `hello` printed first, then `fork()` is executed ?

Also, sometimes it prints:

```
 HelloWorld 
// then the reports....process exited with return value 0..etc etc.. then...//
HelloWorld
```

Why this output ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason is: buffered output. "Hello" is in the buffer but not yet put out when you do the fork, so the forked process starts with the same buffer including the same word "Hello". Then, both the parent and the child output "World" so the total output is "HelloWorld" for both of them.

Comment: … and the solution is to `fflush` before `fork`.

Comment: i'd say thank you :) but it is against the community guidelines i guess :) :D

Comment: No, it's a valid question, but it has been asked before. Happens all the time.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @ammoQ answer:

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello");
    fflush(stdout);
    fork();
    printf("World");
}
```

will get you to the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

Fork creates a copy of the process.  And printf() may be buffered when the fork happens, this buffer would be copied.

Pretty solid explanation here:
[fork() branches more than expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132868/fork-branches-more-than-expected/11133054#11133054][1])

Comment: Hello laser_wizard. It seems like you spotted a duplicate. In this case you should flag the question as a duplicate instead of answering it.