# Why does my forking program double in size after each fork?

Tags: c, unix, fork

So i just want to create a simple forking program that forks 5 children at the rate of 1 per every half second and then displays the date and time when each fork is complete.. so this is the jist of the code

```
int count = 1;
while(count <= 5){
    int kid = fork();

    if(kid == -1){
        perror("error in fork");
        exit(0);
    } else if(!kid){
        numbytes = read(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf)-1);
        buf[numbytes] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n",buf);
    }
    count++;
    usleep(500000); //create per every half second, 500000 = 0.5sec
    close(sockfd);

}


return 0;
```

}

which I thought should be simple enough, but instead of forking 5 times it doubles after each fork.. so it forks 1 time, then 2, then 4, 8.. etc.

Help?

Comment: Because you keep forking in both the parent *and* the child processes. Should maybe the child process *exit* when it's done?

Comment: Also you really should [`wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) for the child processes, or you will have zombie processes that gets orphaned when the parent process exits.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the quick reply, but now i'm having trouble finding out where the wait and exit should be placed.. sorry this is pretty new to me.

Comment: and the exit() at the end of the block after? @Karthikeyan.R.S

Comment: Apologize @Jeans , You should add the `exit` in else if block and `wait` before or after `usleep`.

Comment: Read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fork() branches more than expected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132868/fork-branches-more-than-expected)

Answer (score 3):

A `fork` is generally of this form.

```
    int pid = fork();

    if( pid == -1 ) { /* error */
        fprintf(stderr, "Error forking: %s", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    else if( pid == 0 ) { /* child */
        puts("Child");
        exit(0);
    }

    /* Parent */
    printf("Forked %d\n", pid);
```

Note that the child has to exit else it will continue executing the rest of the program. Usually you have the child process run a function and exit.

The other part is the main program should [`wait`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/wait.htm) until all child processes are complete, else you get [zombies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process). Usually a loop calling `wait()` until there's no more children.

```
int wpid;
int wstatus;
while( (wpid = wait(&wstatus)) != -1 ) {
    printf("Child %d exited with status %d\n", wpid, wstatus);
}
```

Put it all together and here's how you fork and wait for 5 child processes.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int max_children = 5;

    for( int i = 0; i < max_children; i++ ) {
        int pid = fork();

        if( pid == -1 ) { /* error */
            fprintf(stderr, "Error forking: %s", strerror(errno));
        }
        else if( pid == 0 ) { /* child */
            puts("Child");
            exit(0);
        }

        /* Parent */
        printf("Forked %d\n", pid);
    }

    int wpid;
    int wstatus;
    while( (wpid = wait(&wstatus)) != -1 ) {
        printf("Child %d exited with status %d\n", wpid, wstatus);
    }
}
```